# EBUSY when trying to add process to cgroup v2

Tags: linux, cgroups

I'm playing with `cgroups v2` on `Fedora 35` (kernel `5.15.5-200.fc35.x86_64`).

I was able to test `cpu`, `cpuset` and `pids` controllers without any problems. But for `memory`, `hugetlb` or `io` I'm having troubles. Here is a step list how to reproduce this problem for `memory` controller (all commands were executed as a root user):

1. Make sure that memory controller is enabled in root cgroup:

   ```
   # cat cgroup.subtree_control
   cpu io memory hugetlb pids
   ```
2. Create new cgroup:

   ```
   # mkdir example
   # cd example/
   ```
3. Enable memory controller:

   ```
   # echo "+memory" > cgroup.subtree_control
   ```
4. Add process to control group:

   ```
   # echo $$ > cgroup.procs 
   bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
   ```

When I try to first add process to `cgroup` and later enable controller, the same error occurs on last step.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question? Because I am also having the similar difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the cgroups v2 "no internal processes" rule:

```
   The "no internal processes" rule is in fact more subtle than
   stated above.  More precisely, the rule is that a (nonroot)
   cgroup can't both (1) have member processes, and (2) distribute
   resources into child cgroups—that is, have a nonempty
   cgroup.subtree_control file.  Thus, it is possible for a cgroup
   to have both member processes and child cgroups, but before
   controllers can be enabled for that cgroup, the member processes
   must be moved out of the cgroup (e.g., perhaps into the child
   cgroups).

   With the Linux 4.14 addition of "thread mode" (described below),
   the "no internal processes" rule has been relaxed in some cases.
```

source: [cgroups(7)](https://manpath.be/f35/7/cgroups#L557)

---

See also the kernel source code:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/kernel/cgroup/cgroup.c#L2586

```
**
 * cgroup_migrate_vet_dst - verify whether a cgroup can be migration destination
 * @dst_cgrp: destination cgroup to test
 *
 * On the default hierarchy, except for the mixable, (possible) thread root
 * and threaded cgroups, subtree_control must be zero for migration
 * destination cgroups with tasks so that child cgroups don't compete
 * against tasks.
 */
int cgroup_migrate_vet_dst(struct cgroup *dst_cgrp)
{
    // [..]

    /* apply no-internal-process constraint */
    if (dst_cgrp->subtree_control)
        return -EBUSY;

    return 0;
}
```

---

So for example, this works:

```
# cd /sys/fs/cgroup
/sys/fs/cgroup # rmdir deleteme
/sys/fs/cgroup # mkdir deleteme
/sys/fs/cgroup # cd deleteme 
/sys/fs/cgroup/deleteme # mkdir leaf
/sys/fs/cgroup/deleteme # echo '+memory' > cgroup.subtree_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/deleteme # echo $$ > leaf/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/deleteme #
```